# Vue3 Composition API <script setup> variable to use in template

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs3, aws-amplify

I keep finding documentation that says variables defined in the `<script setup>` can be used in the template, but I can't seem to get this (seemingly simple) piece of code to work.

Pulling the 'username' (which is the UUID) from AWS Cognito for the currentAuthenticatedUser, then sending that to DynamoDB through a graphql query to pull the user's data record. When I console.log that information in the function it works perfectly, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to use that variable in the template.

```
<script setup>
  import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-vue";
  import "@aws-amplify/ui-vue/styles.css";
  import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/api';
  import { getStudent } from '../graphql/queries';
  import { getCurrentUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";
  import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
  import config from '../amplifyconfiguration.json';
  import { onMounted } from 'vue';
  Amplify.configure(config);const client = generateClient();
  const firstname = '';

  async function currentAuthenticatedUser() {
    try {
      const { username, userId, signInDetails } = await getCurrentUser();
      return username;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  async function loggedInUserData() {
    const loggedInUserId = await currentAuthenticatedUser(); 
    const response = await client.graphql({
      query: getStudent,
      variables: { id: loggedInUserId }
    });
    console.log(response.data.getStudent.firstname);
    firstname = response.data.getStudent.firstname;
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    loggedInUserData();
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  ...
  ...
        <authenticator>
           <template v-slot="{ user, signOut }">
              <div class="pl-36">Hello {{ firstname }}!</div>
              <button @click="signOut" class="ml-36">Sign Out</button>
           </template>
        </authenticator>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the document you want is this: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html.

You should use the Ref function to declare a state. Head to the link to get more details: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html.

Answer (score 1):

The variable technically is being used in the template, but only using it's initial empty string value because the variable is not [reactive](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#why-refs).

Make sure to define `firstname` as reactive in your code:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
const firstname = ref('')
```

You used `const` without `ref` so actually it was never reassignable to begin with.  We can use `const` with ref/reactive variables because they're now technically Proxy objects and it's their *inner* value that we assign to, hence why we assign new values to refs with the `.value` property:

```js
firstname.value = response.data.getStudent.firstname;
```

Comment: Perfect.... I tried every combination I could think of and originally had the "const firstname = ref(' '); .... but I did NOT have the "firstname.value = " part... thanks so much!